# move a word in a string with spaces as delimiters between words

Tags: c++, c, string

Let me explain my question with more details, using an example.

Given a string:

> "Assonance is the reiteration of the same vowel sound at the beginning
>   of several consecutive words"

If we want to move the fourth word, which is **reiteration**, to the second word's position, the string will become :

> "Assonance reiteration is the of the same vowel sound at the beginning
>   of several consecutive words"

Given a `C` function prototyped as follow :

```
void move(char *s, int word_begin_ind, int word_end_ind, int target_begin_ind)
```

How to implement this function to do the job ?

In the above example, `word_begin_ind = 17, word_end_ind = 27, target_begin_ind = 10`

***This is not a homework***. Actually it's an interview question. I have an algorithm. The basic idea is like:

(1) make a copy of the target word using `word_begin_ind` and `word_end_ind`.

(2) from `target_begin_ind` to `word_begin_ind - 1`, move every character to the right position. For example, move `word_begin_ind-1` to 'word_end_ind', `word_begin_ind-2` to 'word_end_ind-1' and so on.

(3) Finally, move the copy to the right position (beginning from the target_begin_ind).

I hope everyone can understand what I'm asking.

You don't need to use c to do this job. C++ is also welcome.

Can anyone help me find other solutions ?

Comment: it doesn't matter if it's homework or not since that tag is deprecated

Comment: what kind of tag is suitable for this problem?

Comment: algorithm perhaps? manipulation comes to mind. The ones you have work well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Take an range between start of one position and end of other:

   ```
   "Assonance [is the reiteration] of the same vowel sound at the beginning of several consecutive words"
   ```
2. Reverse this range:

   ```
   "Assonance [noitaretier eht si] of the same vowel sound at the beginning of several consecutive words"
   ```
3. Split this range into word and everything-other:

   ```
   "Assonance [noitaretier|eht si] of the same vowel sound at the beginning of several consecutive words"
   ```
4. Reverse word:

   ```
   "Assonance [reiteration|eht si] of the same vowel sound at the beginning of several consecutive words"
   ```
5. Reverse everything-other:

   ```
   "Assonance [reiteration|is the] of the same vowel sound at the beginning of several consecutive words"
   ```
6. So you've done.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it like that:

```
char * temp = malloc(end-begin);
memcpy(temp,s,end-begin);
```

Now we know that in the destination location some space must be made to put the word back in, so I'd want to move n bytes from the destination location back or forth, depending on if the original word is before or after the destination location, that should be done with *memmove*, then just **memcpy** the word at the destination location